# Loop through a PYTHON API call with a limited Row Count per request and Total Rows in the HTTP header?

Tags: python-3.x, http

I am very new to Python.  I've written an API call for a large amount of electricity settlement data largely from the API instructions.  The secured API limits requests to 50,000 rows per request.  The API instructions offer a HTTP response header "X-TotalRows" to assist in looping through the entire data set which may be millions of rows.

**How do I write the loop for the Python call to append all data, 50k rows at a time?**  I've included my code for the initial dataset (rows 1-50,000) but do not know how to use the HTML Header "X-TotalRows" to append the entire data set, 50k at a time.

The instructions recommend looping through the data using the HTML Header "X-TotalRows" and altering the Start Row parameter to be "1 + rowCount".

This may seem elementary but I've searched and experimented for hours and hours trying to crack this code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'xyz', 'content-type': 'application/json'
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'download': 'true',
    'rowCount': '50000',
    'sort': 'datetime_beginning_ept',
    'order': 'asc',
    'startRow': 1,
    'isActiveMetadata': 'true',
    'fields': 'datetime_beginning_utc, datetime_beginning_ept, pnode_id, pnode_name, voltage, equipment, type, zone, system_energy_price_da, total_lmp_da, congestion_price_da, marginal_loss_price_da, row_is_current, version_nbr',
    #'datetime_beginning_utc': '{string}',
    'datetime_beginning_ept': '1-1-2018 00:00 to 1-31-2018 23:00',
    #'pnode_id': '{number}',
    #'pnode_name': '{string}',
    #'voltage': '{string}',
    #'equipment': '{string}',
    #'type': '{string}',
    'zone': 'aep;comed;pseg'
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.pjm.com')
    conn.request("GET", "/api/v1/da_hrl_lmps?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response.status, response.reason)
    data = response.read()
    #print(data)
    conn.close()
    file = open('output.txt', 'w')
    s=str(data)
    file.write(s)
    file.close()
    print("Go to ouput.txt")
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

strtotalcount = response.headers['X-TotalRows']

totalcount = int(strtotalcount)

Then loop through the data using rowcount and totalcount into the file in append mode.